# Excel vba: copy file from one folder to many folders simultaneously

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy files from one directory to several others, I (with searching help and ready code) succeeded in doing that, the problem is :

The macro waits till it finishes copying all files from source to destination 1, then start copying to destination 2

I want either to:

Copy the 1st source to all destinations at the same time then move to source 2
OR start copying all source files to destination 1 then move to start copying all source files to destination 2 **

### without waiting

**:

I use the following to code to copy:

```
Sub All()

    For Each C In Worksheets("Path").Range("A2:A21")
    If C.Value = "" Then GoTo 1
    Call CopyFolder

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Next C

1 
End Sub

'================================================

Sub CopyFolder()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "C:\video"  
    ToPath = C & ":\video"    


    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If fso.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"

        Exit Sub
    End If

    fso.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Sure, first you'll need to buy a second head for your winchester. If you mean you want to give instructions at once, then I recommend creating an **array**.

Comment: Unfortunately, not to familiar with arrays

Comment: Made this array, working but same result:

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this for your 2nd choice solution

I can't test it on my machine right now, but it looks like a good solution to me. (;

```
FileSystemObject.CopyFile Source:= FromPath +"*.FILEEXTENSION", Destination :=ToPath
```

If all your files have similar names in regards of "loopability" (sth. like video1, video2 etc.) you could maybe use something like this:

```
Sub CountAndCopyFiles()
Dim fso As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim objFiles As Object
Dim obj As Object
Dim lngFileCount As Long

FromPath = "C:\video"  


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFiles = fso.GetFolder(FromPath).Files

lngFileCount = objFiles.Count

For Each obj In objFiles
  fso.CopyFile Source:= FromPath & obj.Name, Destination:=ToPath
Next obj

Set objFiles = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set obj = Nothing

End Sub
```

HTH, Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom: Double declaration for fso (fixed), but "FileSystemObject.CopyFile Source:= FromPath & obj.Name, Destination:=ToPath" [Object required]

Answer (score 0):

Tried to make this array, but same waiting result:

```
Sub xArray()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim Drive(1 To 2) As String
  Drive(1) = "O"
    Drive(2) = "P"
For i = 1 To 2
    FromPath = "C:\video"  
    ToPath = Drive(i) & ":\video"   

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If fso.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"

        Exit Sub
    End If
    fso.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without Waiting**

What you want to do is spawn a new, child process (or thread) to do the file copy:

```
fso.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
```

That way, the background thread can execute the file copy, while your code goes on to identify the next file to be copied and kicks off that copy.

As far as I know, this isn't possible in native VBA. You need a compilable language like VB, or C. It's possible that someone will come along who knows the Windows shell objects very well, and can provide you with some shell function calls that will allow you to spawn these child processes, but it would be a pretty in-depth bit of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Using the shell command, I called a .bat file that makes the copy process

Thanks